# Show Document Library from other sitecollection

Tags: list, document-library

I need to show a document library (filtered on criteria) from another site collection (sp2010)

If i add a lists and libraries webpart in my current web i can have full document edit, permissions etc menu available ...

Is there a way i can perform the same thing, so get a filtered list of document 1,2 3 from my document list, but that document list exists in another site collection ?

It is the menu functionality that i would like to keep for the documents if possible...

any help - much appreciated.

Bill

Comment: Ive seen this code on this site ..

xsltlistviewwebpart


http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/4843/reusing-the-xsltlistviewwebpart

Is this the sort of thing that will solve my issue?

Comment: didn't tried, but maybe a custom BCS relying on the SP web services can help you, keeping the UI integration

Answer (score 1):

To break the site collection boundary, you're going to need to create a custom web part or use a tool like the Lightning Conductor web part from Lightning Tools or a Bamboo Solutions equivalent.

Comment: Ill look into the lighning conductor though - see what thats about.

What i am looking into now (but not getting there yet ;-( ) is the dataviewwebpart and trying to pass in the parameters ? 

Is that feasable?

I have a number of connected webparts on a page ... one providor, several consumers ... I want to get an id from the providor and populate and filter the document library from another web...

Thanks 

Bill

Comment: Possibly, you'll have to use a web service as the datasource for the DVWP most likely.